Transact SQL geography polygon contains point
I have a polygon surrounding the country of Luxemburg (Europe).
I have two points:

one (more or less) in the center of Luxemburg City (Luxemburg)
one (more of less) in the center of Brussels (Belgium)

The first point should be in the polygon, the second one should not. Although I create the polygon counter-clockwise, Contains returns true (1) for both points.
Code:
declare @points table (locationcode nvarchar(max), latitude real, longitude float, info nvarchar(max), ord int)
declare  @locationcode nvarchar(max) = 'LUX'
insert into @points values
    ('LUX', 50.264980, 6.650216, 'right top', 1),
    ('LUX', 50.294766, 5.345107, 'left top', 2),
    ('LUX', 49.307025, 5.430560, 'left bottom', 3),
    ('LUX', 49.322218, 6.657984, 'right bottom', 4),
    ('LUX', 50.264980, 6.650216, 'right top', 5)

declare @buildstring nvarchar(max)
select @buildstring = coalesce(@buildstring + ', ','') + convert(nvarchar,latitude) + ' ' +  convert(nvarchar,longitude) from @points where locationcode = @locationcode order by ord
declare @polygon geography = 'POLYGON((' + @buildstring + '))'
print 'polygon:'
print @polygon.ToString()
print @polygon.STIsValid()
-- point in polygon coordinates:
declare @pointInLatitude float
declare @pointInLongitude float
declare  @pointIn geography
-- point out of polygon coordinates:
declare @pointOutLatitude float
declare @pointOutLongitude float
declare @pointOut geography
-- +/- center Luxenbourg city (Luxembourg):
set @pointInLatitude = 49.609133
set @pointInLongitude = 6.136210
set @pointIn = geography::Point(@pointInLatitude, @pointInLongitude, 4326)
-- +/- center Brussels city: (Belgium)
set @pointOutLatitude = 50.847726
set @pointOutLongitude = 4.349612
set @pointOut = geography::Point(@pointOutLatitude, @pointOutLongitude, 4326)

select @polygon.STContains(@pointIn) , @polygon.STContains(@pointOut)


When creating the polygon WKT, you need to order your coordinates as longitude latitude instead of latitude longitude. Think if the coordinates as being x y with x being the horizontal axis (longitude) and y being the vertical axis (latitude). (However, in contrast to this, the geography::Point() function takes parameters as latitude, longitude, swapping them around internally as can be seen with a print @pointIn.ToString(). Why this inconsistency exists is beyond me.)

Aside... as a quick check, when using SSMS you can SELECT @polygon and examine the results on the Spatial results tab. If you see that the world is all blue, or the polygon is misshapen, then your polygon isn't defined correctly.

With the correct order it works https://dbfiddle.uk/fm6jceFG. Note also that polygons must always use Left Hand Rule, so you are "walking" the polygon from the outside with the line on your left.

Also you can use EnvelopeAggregate instead of strings to make your polygon https://dbfiddle.uk/X7pK7TGY

A caution about EnvelopeAggregate() and ConvexHullAggregate() (from the above fiddle ): Neither produce precise boundaries matching the intended polygon and will ignore/discard any concave (inward penetrating) boundary features. Consider a board with several nails placed at random, with no defined order. I believe that ConvexHullAggregate() is equivalent of stretching a rubber band around the outer perimeter, not touching any nails that fall in the middle. EnvelopeAggregate() appears to work similarly, except that it returns a circular string. Fiddle.

A note on precision: Depending on your required accuracy, a real datatype might not provide the required precision - especially when cast to character using convert(nvarchar, latitude). If you only need accuracy to the city level (1km+), real may be acceptable. However, if you need accuracy at the building level or better (less than 100m precision) you should probably use float. Also, consider using convert(nvarchar, latitude, 3), where 3 selects "lossless conversion", for your text conversions. Also ensure that all of your input data is represented with sufficient accuracy.
